# issue with getting image resizing and cropping to work under node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, multer, lwip

I can't get my head around image processing in node js. Sadly AND gladly this will be an important part of my application.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

1) User updloads an image (=> multipart formdata gets send to the server containing all data. This works great)
2) Resize that picture to a max width of 640px.
3) Crop that picture from Y-axis: some_variable to Y-axis some_variable + max_height (240) and X-axis: 0 to X-axis 640px
4) Save it like that on the server.

Here is my current miserable approach with **multer** and **lwip**

Example picture data:

```
Files { fieldname: 'picture_data',
  originalname: 'dog-how-to-select-your-new-best-friend-thinkstock99062463.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: 'public/imgs/',
  filename: '1-picture_data-1453136557949.jpg',
  path: 'public/imgs/1-picture_data-1453136557949.jpg',
  size: 1790149 }
```

This data gets received by my router in this function:

```
router.post('/someCall', upload.single('picture_data'), function(req, response) {
...
});
```

Now the multer upload function gets called:

```
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/imgs/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    // CHECK IF FILE IS TOO BIG
    var fileSize = file.size;
    File_controller.checkFeedPostFileSize(fileSize, function(err, res){
      if(res == "File size ok"){
        var mimeType = file.mimetype;
        File_controller.checkMimeTypeImage(mimeType, function(err, res){
          // FILE IS OK AND MAY BE SAVED.
          if(res == "Mimetype ok"){
            var ending = ".jpg";
            if(mimeType == "image/jpeg"){
              ending = ".jpg";
            }else if(mimeType = "image/png"){
              ending = ".png";
            }
            var filename = req.session.user.id + "-" + file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + ending;
            req.session.user.file_name = filename;
            cb(null, filename);

            var path = 'public/imgs/' + req.session.user.filename;
            lwip.open(path, function(err, image){
              if (err) return console.log("LWIP BILD NICHT GEFUNDEN", err);
              image.resize(640, function(){

              });
            });
          }else{
            //response.send("Error: Mimetype not ok");
          }
        });
      }else{
        //response.send("Error: File size too big");
      }
    });
  }
```

});

Now that approach works until the **lwip** part. Which means the file gets saved to the server in its original upload size. As far as I understand the module lwip should now open the image from the server then resize it *and save it again*.

This approach is pretty awkward and I am sure it can be done right on the way before saving and reopening the file. But if you help me to get it to work in any way I'd be super thankful.

If any information is missing to solve this problem please let me know. I will not hesitate to include everything necessary.

Thank you

Comment: So basically everything is working?

Comment: nope - the cropping / resizing part isnt working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open the image in your router handler, which will be called once the file exists on the file system. Both options on `diskStorage` are called prior to the file being fully uploaded. Remove the lwip part from `filename`, and try something along the lines of this instead:

```
router.post('/someCall', upload.single('picture_data'), function(req, response) {

    lwip.open(req.file.path, function(err, image){

        image.batch()
            .resize(640)
            .writeFile('output.jpg', function(err){
                if (err){
                    response.status(400).send({ error: err.toString() });
                }
                else {
                    response.status(200).end();
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay, do I need some sort of save function afterwards?

Comment: What do you mean with save function?

Comment: Like saving the resized file :)

Comment: I just tried your approach and basically nothing happens. The file is still on my server with its original size of 2400px width

Comment: Sure, you can save the file, but that's a different question. Just follow the [lwip documentation](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip#usage). Updated the example, in any case.

Comment: Remember to hange `output.jpg` to whatever you want the file to be named.

Comment: This worked just fine. Thank you. Do you know if I can pipe .resize again after writeFile in order to create multiple images with different sizez?

Comment: Cool, glad to hear so. It should be possible to chain further commands, you'd have to order the resize6 operations to avoid losing quality. Not sitting in front the screen anymore, though, can take a look at it later again